# Storing a dictionary in swift in permanent storage

Tags: swift, storage, permanent

this code here throws an error when I run the app

```
var dic :[NSObject: AnyObject] = ["name":"steph" , "status": "unemployed"]

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "diction")

var retrievedDict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("diction")! as NSDictionary

let g = dic["name"]

println(g)
```

what's wrong with this?

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: "Swift dynamic cast failed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Dictionary key has to be a String. So instead of declaring it [NSObject: AnyObject] you have to declare it as [String: AnyObject]. Also you are trying to load it from dic but you have to load it from retrievedDict.

update: **Xcode 7.2 • Swift 2.1.1**

```
let dic:[String: AnyObject] = ["name":"steph" , "status": "unemployed"]

NSUserDefaults().setObject(dic, forKey: "diction")

if let retrievedDict = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("diction") {
    if let g = retrievedDict["name"] as? String {
        print(g)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Your only problem is, that you pass the wrong object to your `NSUserDefaults`. You should pass the `dic` instead of `array`.

So change that:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "diction")
```

to that:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dic, forKey: "diction")
```